# Custom browser not working in android

Tags: android, android-webview

i have made a simple custom browsaer in android ,With very basic controlls having refresh and back,and an edittext for Url,I want to make is when user ener any url and click on "go" button ,It should open that page in the same browser(not in default browser).I have implemented as below:but my "go" button not working.It displays "webpage not found" all time.So Please help me for this My code is as below:

**subheader.java**

```
package com.example.browserdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SubHeader extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener {

    private Context context;

    public ImageView btn_back;
    public TextView txtTitle;
    public ImageView btn_reload;
    public EditText et_url;
    public Button go;

    public SubHeader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public SubHeader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(
                R.layout.uc_sub_header, this, true);

        this.btn_back = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        this.btn_reload = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reload);
        this.go = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.go);
        this.et_url = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_url);

        this.btn_back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_back) {
            ((Activity) this.context).finish();
        }

    }
}
```

**main.java**

```
package com.example.browserdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView Browser;
    public SubHeader subHeader;
    public EditText et_url;
    public Button go;
    public ImageView btn_back, btn_reload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        this.subHeader = (SubHeader) findViewById(R.id.menu_header);
        this.subHeader.btn_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.subHeader.btn_reload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        btn_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_reload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_reload);
        Browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        et_url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_url);
        go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);

        btn_reload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Browser.reload();
            }
        });
        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String theWebsite = et_url.getText().toString();
                Browser.loadUrl(theWebsite);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Browser.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Browser.canGoBack()) {
                    Browser.goBack();
                }

            }
        });
        generateUI();
    }

    public void generateUI() {

        new GetRealTimeUrl().execute();

    }

    public class GetRealTimeUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public ProgressDialog mProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.mProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            this.mProgress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            this.mProgress.setCancelable(false);
            this.mProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
            this.mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
            Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            Browser.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
            Browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            Browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            this.mProgress.hide();
            this.mProgress.dismiss();

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.arg1 = 1;

            handler.sendMessage(msg);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.arg1 == 1) {
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, could you please provide your logs or some more details so that problem is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, would be best to see a log file for the errors or the contents of logcat

One thing i noticed which i want to ask and point out at the same time, with the override of shouldOverrideUrlLoading... This should be before loading a URL....

Try placing `Browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");`

In front of `Browser.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);`

In my understanding, the flow of the program is to set the listeners/overrides first so they are ready to respond and then load the URL that you want to intercept.

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure - Have you added the following permission in your manifest file? -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```